# How to make 3 horizontal elements stack up on top of each other if the screen is narrow enough

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I have 3 elements laid out in a table:

```
<table>
<tr><td><img /> <span>example</span></td>
<td><img /> <span>example</span></td>
<td><img /> <span>example</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Which works great responsively (table has width of 100%) and shrinks down when I shrink the browser window. But when I shrink the window too small, it squishes up the table cells, I would rather it stacked the table cells vertically at a certain width.

Can this be achieved with divs in twitter bootstrap? If so, how. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the fluid or fixed grid system instead of a table. [This example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.2/examples/hero.html) shows something similar to what your talking about. The code you have above would look more like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <img/><span>example</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img/><span>example</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <img/><span>example</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) explains more about the grid system. By including the responsive CSS file the columns within the grid will stack vertically when your viewport shrinks to below 767px wide.

Comment: Do you know how to change the 767px figure to a number of my own choosing? Then I can do it. Thanks

Comment: Sure, just change or override the thresholds set in the bootstrap-responsive.css file. [This page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) describes a little bit about how they work. The lines you want to change are
    `@ media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){...},
    @ media (max-width: 767px) { ... }, and
    @ media (max-width: 480px) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You should use  with float set. This will help them stack up when the space is narrowed down. Further, you can set a minimum width parameter so that they do not shrink after a limit.